# How to read a collection of entities with complex properties in olingo?

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I am roughly following this [Tutorial](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/od4_basic_read.html) from apache olingo page. I want to read a collection of entities that have complex properties.

Setting up the provider, I get the following output when accessing `http://localhost:8080/api/odata/$metadata`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="My.Namespace">
            <EntityType Name="MyEntity">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
                <Property Name="name" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
                <Property Name="description" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
                <Property Name="complexProp" Type="My.Namespace.MyComplexType"></Property>
            </EntityType>
            <ComplexType Name="MyComplexType">
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
                <Property Name="name" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
            </ComplexType>
            <EntityContainer Name="Container">
                <EntitySet Name="MyEntities" EntityType="My.Namespace.MyEntity"></EntitySet>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Which seems to be ok for me (is it?). But wenn I try to read a collection of my entities accessing `http://localhost:8080/api/odata/MyEntities`, I get the return message

```
Cannot find type with name: My.Namespace.MyComplexType
```

And stepping into the code reveals a thrown expection in the `readEntityCollection` method of the processor when `entityCollection` is called on the serializer.

I must miss an important point, because it seems to me that `My.Namespace.MyComplexType` is clearly defined.

Comment: Please comment if you think the ``$metadata`` output is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the exception was thrown in the processor, the error did not have anything to do with serialization.

The complex type `MyComplexType` could not be found, because only `getEntityType(final FullQualifiedName entityTypeName)` was overridden in the EdmProvider, but not `getComplexType(final FullQualifiedName complexTypeName)`. `olingo` seems to search for types by calling these methods.

After overriding this method all data was properly displayed.